# What is the use of bootstrap subthemes in Drupal7?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

Whats is the use of Bootstrap sub theme in Drupal 7 and why it is recommended? There is lot of articles out there on "How to Bootstrap sub-theming" but none of them are available for why?

Answer (score 0):

As it is said on Drupal.org:

> Sub-themes are just like any other theme, with one difference: They
>   inherit the parent theme's resources.

A Bootstrap sub-theme allows you to inherit from the **[Bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/)** itself. It brings you several benefits:

- No need to download any contrib modules, the Bootstrap sub-theme kit should be enough.
- A strong CSS base, with accurate variables customization.
- Respect of web standards.
- Great modularity.
- ...

I hope I answered the question.